# Progress bar for unknown Rally query size

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar, rally

I'm using Rally (currently SDK 1.32, but I'm in the process of migrating to 2.0) to query for projects within a given workspace, which are then loaded into an HTML dropdown bar, and I'm trying to have a progress bar display the progress of the query via javascript.

Because the Rally query simply returns a single JSON data packet, I'm not sure what I'd use to measure the progress that's being made. I'm using a progress bar as opposed to a spinner because I'm leveraging responsive Twitter/Bootstrap. I know that bootstrap has the striped progress bar, but that isn't compatible with certain versions of IE, so I was trying to avoid using that as well. If there isn't a good option other than the spinner or the striped progress bar, I guess I'll just have to deal.

Does anybody know of a way to have the progress bar meaningfully display the progress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to determine if a Rally App is partially complete would be to determine what percentage of pages Rally had returned. Since we limit the size to 200 objects per page you can get a decent estimate of your progress for long running queries based upon those pages.